# how can I generate items with different background colors when clicked on a button that add a to do list?

Tags: javascript, events

I am doing a to do list and I want to show a new item with different background color from the previous and next item.
I want to give 3 colors options (example:blue, green, pink) and when click it will show interspersed. If the first one is blue, the next one will be green or pink. Like this example: [image](https://cssanimation.rocks/list-items/).

My code so far:

```
const button = document.querySelector('#add-to-list');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){

  let newLI = document.createElement('li');
  newLI.textContent = 'A new item';
  list.appendChild(newLI);

  setTimeout(function(){
    newLI.classList = "show";
  },10);  
})
```

```
*,
*::before,
*::after{
   margin:0;
   padding:0; 
}

html,
body {
  height:100vh;
}

section{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  list-style:none;
  background:#d1703c;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:2em;
  padding:0 0.5em;
  width:10em;
  height:0;
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li.show {
  height:2em;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.fade li {
  transition:all 0.4s ease-out;
  opacity:0;

}

.fade li.show {
  opacity:1;
}

.swing{
  perspective:100px;
}

.swing li {
  opacity:0;
  transform:rotateY(-90deg);
  transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.64,.34,1.76);
}

.swing li.show{
  opacity:1;
  transform:none;
  transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.64,.34,1.76);
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Animating List Items</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">   
      <div class="fade swing">
        <ul id="list"></ul>
      </div>
      <button id="add-to-list">Add a list item</button>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="js/todoList.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with 2 more js line. Define a colors array, and use a modulo operation to select the appropriate color index when creating a new button, something like this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#add-to-list');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');
const colors = ["red","blue","green","yellow"];
button.addEventListener('click', function(){

    let newLI = document.createElement('li');
    newLI.textContent = 'A new item';
    
    //select color index based on the number of item in the list modulo the number of color
    newLI.style.backgroundColor =  colors[list.childNodes.length % colors.length];
    
    list.appendChild(newLI);


    setTimeout(function(){
        newLI.classList = "show";
    },10);


});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
   margin:0;
   padding:0; 
}

html,
body {
  height:100vh;
}

section{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  list-style:none;
  background:#d1703c;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:2em;
  padding:0 0.5em;
  width:10em;
  height:0;
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li.show {
  height:2em;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.fade li {
  transition:all 0.4s ease-out;
  opacity:0;

}

.fade li.show {
  opacity:1;
}

.swing{
  perspective:100px;
}

.swing li {
  opacity:0;
  transform:rotateY(-90deg);
  transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.64,.34,1.76);
}

.swing li.show{
  opacity:1;
  transform:none;
  transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.64,.34,1.76);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Animating List Items</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">   
      <div class="fade swing">
        <ul id="list"></ul>
      </div>
      <button id="add-to-list">Add a list item</button>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="js/todoList.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much François Huppé =)